# Flutter firestore shared preference double type data issue

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter app, When users sign up and I need to save double type "height" data and I am using `SharedPreferences` for this but I have an issue.

This is my `SharedPreferences` code:

```
static Future<bool> saveUserWeightSharedPreference(double userWeight) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await prefs.setDouble(sharedPreferenceUserLoggedInKey, userWeight);
}
```

and this is my sign up function where is my using `SharedPreferences`. The error is:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'double'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [spor3]
> lib\login\signup.dart:52)

```
  signMeUp(){

    if(formKey.currentState.validate()){

      Map<String, String> userInfoMap = {
        "name":userNameTextEditingController.text,
        "email": emailTextEditingController.text,
        "height": heightTextEditingController.text,
        "weight": weightTextEditingController.**text**, // this "text" codes not working
        "weightTwo": weightTwoTextEditingController.text,
      };

      HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(emailTextEditingController.text);
      HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(userNameTextEditingController.text,);
      HelperFunctions.saveUserHeightSharedPreference(heightTextEditingController.text,);
      HelperFunctions.saveUserWeightSharedPreference(weightTextEditingController.**text**,);// and this 
      "text" codes not working
      HelperFunctions.saveUserWeightTwoSharedPreference(weightTwoTextEditingController.text,);




      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      authMethods.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(emailTextEditingController.text, passwordTextEditingController.text).then((val){



        databaseMethods.uploadUserInfoTwo(userInfoMap);
        HelperFunctions.saveUserLoggedInSharedPreference(true);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
      });
    }
  }
```

EDIT 1: I changed my signMeUp() function but this time I have another issue

```
signMeUp(){


if(formKey.currentState.validate()){

  Map<String, dynamic> userInfoMap = {
    "name":userNameTextEditingController.text,
    "email": emailTextEditingController.text,
    "height": heightTextEditingController.text,
    "weight": double.parse(weightTextEditingController.text),
    "weightTwo": weightTwoTextEditingController.text,
  };

  HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(emailTextEditingController.text);
  HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSharedPreference(userNameTextEditingController.text,);
  HelperFunctions.saveUserHeightSharedPreference(heightTextEditingController.text,);
  HelperFunctions.saveUserWeightSharedPreference(double.parse(weightTextEditingController.text),);
  HelperFunctions.saveUserWeightTwoSharedPreference(weightTwoTextEditingController.text,);

  
  setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
  });
  authMethods.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(emailTextEditingController.text, passwordTextEditingController.text).then((val){

    
    databaseMethods.uploadUserInfoTwo(userInfoMap);
    HelperFunctions.saveUserLoggedInSharedPreference(true);
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()));
  });
}
}
```

issue:

> The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture:
> Invalid double

> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      double.parse (dart:core-patch/double_patch.dart:111:28)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextEditingController` always returns a `String` for `text` property [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/text.html). So, you need to just parse it to double & then pass it to your function.

```
HelperFunctions.saveUserWeightSharedPreference(double.parse(weightTextEditingController.text),);
```

Comment: when I did this flutter give this issue:    The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Invalid double

Comment: "weight": double.parse(weightTextEditingController.text),    
 
 
 HelperFunctions.saveUserWeightSharedPreference(double.parse(weightTextEditingController.text),);                                                I changed like that

Comment: If user has entered the value which can't be parsed as `double` you'll get an exception. You need to validate the input or/and use `tryParse` instead: `double.tryParse(blahblah) ?? 0.0` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/tryParse.html